# VLC , remember icecast radio station names

Tags: ubuntu, vlc-media-player

When I use VLC (under Ubuntu 11.10) and I go to icecast directory it lists a bunch of radio stations with "unspecified name".

When I double click each station to listen it gets the name of the station.
However when I restart VLC

Answer (score 1):

Update to [VLC 2.0.2](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/releases/2.0.2.html) and it should work like a charm